# Always returns null in Firebase REST API with postman

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, postman

I'm trying to send a request for My firebase database to get all the data by Postman and my data inserted manually but always the result is null

and my URL is

I tried two below URLs with no luck:

https://**myprojectId**.firebaseio.com/**mycollectionName.json**?auth=**Database secret Auth**

and

https://**myprojectId**.firebaseio.com/*rest*/**mycollectionName.json**?auth=**Database secret Auth**

Comment: Are you using Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: Cloud firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs you are using are for the [Realtime Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data), not for the Cloud Firestore REST API.

The doc for the Cloud Firestore REST API is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest). Look at [this specific section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.databases.documents) for fetching documents and collections.